# How to stretch image contained in a local html to load in UIWebView for varying ios form factors devices?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iphone, uiwebview

I have a local html file test.html as follows -

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:transparent;">
        <img src="Image.png" width='100%' height='100%' />
    </body>
</html>
```

I load this html in a UIWebView as follows -

```
[self.mWebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
```

It loads fine and shows the Image.png inside webview when run on iPhone 5 but when I run the app on iPad Mini or iPhone 6 or iPhone 6 plus, the image does not show up.

The image has dimensions of 320x480. I suppose that is causing the problem. It isn't stretching on devices of higher form factor.

Please help. Thanks !!

Comment: Perhaps it is produced by `maximum-scale=1.0`. Try to replace this value.

Comment: Do you want me to remove it altogether?

Comment: No. Only replace `maximum-scale=1.0` by `maximum-scale=10.0` for example.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. :-(